Meta User link in main site user profile
I am from Math.SE!  This is my first day on Chin.SE.
I am shocked that there is no "Meta User" link (on the right hand side, next to "Network Profile") in the user profile on the main site.

Compare this with Math.SE.

Can the SE team add this back?  This is, IMHO, quite useful.
